# Crystal report too slow from Visual Studio 2019 and Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a form that prints some reports created with Crystal Report (13.030) and Visual Studio 2019. The printing of each report takes about 5/8 seconds. I have tried all the suggestions found on google, but have not solved anything. Since the reports are about 10m, the customer has to wait a long time before being able to continue.

I have read that it is a known problem, but I don't know how to fix it. I've been thinking about doing the prints in a BackgroundWorker, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

I checked the No printer in report box. This is one of my reports, which are all very similar. Am I wrong something?

```
ReportDocument myReport = new ReportDocument();                           
myReport.Load("myreport.rpt");
PrintLayoutSettings PrintLayout = new PrintLayoutSettings();
PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
printerSettings.PrinterName = "PDF Creator"; // Any;
PageSettings pSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings);

myReport.SetParameterValue("var1", "123"); 
myReport.SetParameterValue("var2", "ABC"); 
myReport.SetParameterValue("var3", "DEF"); 

myReport.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pSettings, false, PrintLayout);

myReport.Close();
```

Comment: Why -1? It should justify it.

Comment: Crystal reports is a paid product, if a basic report takes a long time, it makes sense to talk to them no, they would be the best people to debug your problem?

Comment: The version I use is integrated with Visual Studio 2019, it is not paid, however I have already tried and they have not given me any solution.
I was hoping someone else had the same problem as me and could help me.

Comment: All good, good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the prints to as many BackgroundWorkers, obviously everything is very fast, even if I don't know if it's the best solution.